# How to to make layout transparent so that able to see device screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app which contains layout with a Linear layout with some views. What I want to make main layout background color transparent so that when I launch the app then I must be able to see transparent layout no any color. How do I do that

code:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Camera"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/amazon"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/textColor"
    app:civ_border_width="5dp"
    app:civ_fill_color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/notification_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the Activity to be Translucent in the manifest:

```
<activity ... 
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 
      .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change LinearLayout background attribute to.

```
"@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the Device screen you have to make the LinearLayout and the background of the activity both transparent. Try this:

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android)